# Updating for dark mode: NSColor ignores appearance changes?

Tags: cocoa, nscolor, macos-mojave

In my web view, I'm using CSS variables to change various colors at runtime depending on whether macOS 10.14's dark mode is enabled. That much is working fine. The tricky part is updating the colors when the system appearance changes.

I'm detecting the change by observing the `effectiveAppearance` property on the window. That notification comes through as expected, but when I go to update the colors, `NSColor` still gives me the dark mode colors (or whichever mode the app started up in). For example, `NSColor.textColor` is is still white instead of black when I'm responding to a switch from dark mode to light. The same seems to happen with my own color assets.

Is there a different way or time that I should get these colors? Or could this be an OS bug?

**Edit:**
I also tried creating a subclass of `WebView` and updating my colors in `drawRect()` if the name of the web view's effective appearance changes. The first time, I get all light colors, even when the app starts up in dark mode. After that, when I switch from light mode to dark, I get the dark versions of system colors and light versions of asset catalog colors.

Outside the debugger, switching to dark mode works, but the initial load always gets light colors.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Changing the system appearance doesn't change the *current* appearance, [which you can query and set and is independent from the system appearance](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsappearance/1531945-current). But the appearance actually depends on the "owning" view as within the same view hierarchy, several appearances may occur thanks to vibrancy and also manually setting the `appearance` property on a view.

Cocoa already [updates the current appearance](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/supporting_dark_mode_in_your_interface#2993898) in a few situations, like in `drawRect:`, `updateLayer`, `layout` and `updateConstraints`. Everywhere else, you should do it like this:

```
NSAppearance * saved = [NSAppearance currentAppearance];
[NSAppearance setCurrentAppearance:someView.effectiveAppearance];

// Do your appearance-dependent work, like querying the CGColor from
// a dynamic NSColor or getting its RGB values.

[NSAppearance setCurrentAppearance:saved];
```

Comment: That works for system colors, but for colors from my asset catalog it always returns the light version.

Comment: @Uncommon: It does work for asset colors in my project, so what are you doing with these colors? One thing you might want to try: `NSColor * concrete = [NSColor colorWithCGColor:assetColor.CGColor];` (inside the appearance block I've described in the answer).

Comment: I convert the color to device RGB color space and get the RGB components so that I can pass it into the web view as a CSS RGB color.. I tried the `CGColor` round trip and it didn't help.

Comment: @Uncommon: And you do that inside the snippet I posted in this answer? Try setting a breakpoint or add an `NSLog` and look at the `effectiveAppearance` you are setting to be the current appearance. Does that match what you are seeing on screen?

Comment: Yes, I do it inside a block like that, and the appearance name is always as expected. Code is here: https://github.com/Uncommon/Xit/blob/setAppearance/Xit/FileView/Previews/WebViewController.swift#L98 ...with `NSColor.cssRGB` defined here: https://github.com/Uncommon/Xit/blob/setAppearance/Xit/Utils/MiscExtensions.swift#L37

Comment: @Uncommon: I just checked out your repository. 1) There's crash since you do `webView.window!` in `viewWillAppear` since view is not added to window yet. 2) You should observe the `effectiveAppearance` of your (web)view, not its window. This also resolves the crash. 3) There's a lot of hard-coded colors in the generated HTML (right-click, inspect element; via BlameViewController); these won't change the way you are doing it right now and you need to think how to handle these. The text color does change, for example, since it's using CSS class that you are setting in `updateColors`.

Comment: Oh, and likewise in `updateColors`, assign the `effectiveAppearance` of your `webView`, not its window. These may be different.

Comment: Yeah, I just barely found that crash :) . I originally tried using the view's `effectiveAppearance`, but it wasn't working, so I used the window instead. Now I tried using the view again.. and it worked! No idea what made the difference this time. Thanks for your help, and especially for taking a thorough look at the code!

Comment: @DarkDust, If you don't mind, updated your answer with documentation references? ✌️

Comment: @IanBytchek: Thanks, I tried to further improve on that.

Answer (score 4):

And a Swifty version of the solution proposed by DarkDust:

```
extension NSAppearance {
    static func withAppAppearance<T>(_ closure: () throws -> T) rethrows -> T {
        let previousAppearance = NSAppearance.current
        NSAppearance.current = NSApp.effectiveAppearance
        defer {
            NSAppearance.current = previousAppearance
        }
        return try closure()
    }
}
```

that you can use with

```
NSAppearance.withAppAppearance {
    let bgColor = NSColor.windowBackgroundColor
    // ...
}
```

Note that I'm taking appearance from NSApp but it could be from a NSWindow or NSView.

Comment: This generic function is a good idea. I would recommend to make it an extension of `NSView` and use the view's `effectiveAppearance`, though. Depending on the view hierarchy (vibrancy, overridden appearance) the appearance of a view may be different than the app's appearance.

Comment: How can I use it inside AppDelegate?

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by @chrstphrchvz, `NSAppearance.current` is deprecated when using macOS 11 or newer. The new way to update anything with the latest appearance system settings works like this:

```
NSAppearance.currentDrawing().performAsCurrentDrawingAppearance {
    // Update your window or control or whatever
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The [`currentAppearance` property](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsappearance/1531945-current) used in previous answers is now deprecated. The alternative as of macOS 11 Big Sur is to use the [`performAsCurrentDrawingAppearance:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsappearance/3674525-performascurrentdrawingappearanc) instance method.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSApplication.shared.effectiveAppearance.performAsCurrentDrawingAppearance {
    self.layer?.backgroundColor = colorCustom?.cgColor 
}
```