# How to resolve NSColor manually with specific color scheme (system appearance)?

Tags: swift, appkit, nscolor

According to [NSColor Document](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nscolor), "Colors created from assets can adapt automatically to system appearance changes". However, I want to manually get its color in specific system appearance. For example, as shown below, I create a color set `Color` in assets catalog. And I want to use its dark mode color in light mode, maybe some thing like `NSColor(named: "Color")!.darkModeVariant`.

[image]

I think this problem can be summarized as retrieving NSColor from dynamic color (light and dark) to a single color. I know this can be done in iOS UIKit like below, but how can I achieve it in macOS AppKit?

```
extension UIColor {
    var lightModeVariant: UIColor {
        resolvedColor(with: UITraitCollection(userInterfaceStyle: .light))
    }
    var darkModeVariant: UIColor {
        resolvedColor(with: UITraitCollection(userInterfaceStyle: .dark))
    }
}
```

Comment: The following answer may point you towards a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63859580/20287183